# Do primitive lymph nodes exist in 12th week embryo?

Tags: embryology

Someone told me that primitive lymph nodes do not exist during this week.
However, others say they can.

Here is a picture about inguinal lymph nodes from [here](http://www.embryology.ch/anglais/qblood/lymphat05.html).
No primary lymph nodes are visible (like circular) at 56th day:

[image]

**When are the primitive lymph nodes formed?**

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://discovery.lifemapsc.com/library/review-of-medical-embryology/chapter-128-development-of-the-lymphatic-system) webpage. I think it answers your question.

Comment: @Chris I would like to have some trustworthy source, because the one who claimed that there is no primitive lymph nodes at that time is a smart person. There is something recent research going on by which you can say that those lymph nodes at 3rd month cannot be anymore called primitive lymph nodes. Something new has been discovered by which you can reject the primitive lymph nodes that early. However, I was not told the reason for that. However, this is only research so can be false too; still the claim which I heard today was expressed very strongly.

Comment: Then do it the usual way: A person which makes strong claims needs to have strong proofs as well. In this case the original studies. I can have a look later...

Comment: @Chris Anything found?